# Distributional Convergence to Self-Adjoint Operator on Hilbert Space: Multiplicity of Discrete Spectrum

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am following up on a prior post ([Self-adjoint operators, distributions and spectral theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4242450/self-adjoint-operators-distributions-and-spectral-theorem)) with a more specific question:

Let $H_1$ be the Hilbert space of all square integrable functions, $L^2(\mathbb{R)}$, defined on $(a,b),$ for $a,b>0$ taken with the standard inner product, $<f,g>=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)$. We have $\int_{a}^{b}|g(x)|^2dx<\infty$.

Let $H_2$ be a complete subspace of $H_1$, also a Hilbert Space. We also have a not necessarily bounded self-adjoint operator, $L$ which maps $u \in H_2 \to H_2$.

Furthermore, we have a system of functions over an infinite set of real numbers, $\phi_i(\theta_i)$, which converges to $L$ as a distribution- when integrated against a test function. In other words, suppose, $ Lu=v$, then we have a series of functions $\phi_i$ over all $\theta_i$, which takes in $u$ and outputs a distribution which converges to $v$. Perhaps something like

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\omega_i\phi(\theta_i) \approx{Lu}$$
$$ \omega_i=\langle\phi(\theta_i),u\rangle$$

where $\approx$ is only achieved after integrating the LHS against a test function.
we also know that the $\phi$'s are orthogonal for $\theta_i \neq \theta_j$:
$$<\phi_i(\theta_i),\phi_j(\theta_j)>=0$$ iif $\theta_i \neq \theta_j$

My objective is to be able to say something about the multiplicity of the $\theta_i$'s. If we had some type of convergence (other than the distribution), we could use the spectral theorem to say that $\theta_i$'s are unique/not defective.

I have looked into Rigged Hilbert space, but my understanding is that machinery is mostly used to make sense of continuous spectrum (which i am sure i do not have). And i am unsure if i can use Hilbert-Schmidt theorem to conclude anything here.

Is it possible to use the self-adjointness of $L$, or another argument, to conclude that no $\theta_i$ has multiplicity $m>1$?